# jQuery how to get json { "InputName":"Value"...}

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Hi I have a HTML Form that I would like to serialize using jQuery but I want to get the format like this:

```
{ "Message":"message textg","Tags":"tags text","Facebook":"true"...}
```

The inputs I have in my form are:

```
<textarea name="Message" rows="5" value="" required />
<input type="text" name="Tags" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="Facebook" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="Twitter" checked="checked">
<textarea name="FacebookText" rows="5" value="" />
<textarea rows="5" name="TwitterText" value="" />
```

If I do:

`JSON.stringify($('#form-message').serialize());` then I get a string:

```
"Message=Message+text&Tags=Tags&Facebook=on&FacebookText=Facebook+text&Twitter=on&TwitterText=Twitter+text"
```

If I do:

`JSON.stringify($('#form-message').serializeArray());` then I get a string:

```
[{"name":"Message","value":"Message Text"},{"name":"Tags","value":"Tags"},{"name":"Facebook","value":"on"},{"name":"FacebookText","value":"Facebook Text"},{"name":"Twitter","value":"on"},{"name":"TwitterText","value":"Twitter Text"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, you JSON.stringify a string. Which will return wrong results. Try this instead:

```
var paramObj = {};
$.each($('#form-message').serializeArray(), function(_, kv) {
 paramObj[kv.name] = kv.value;
});
var data = JSON.stringify(paramObj);
```